# How to change the attributes of a file inside an archive

Tags: attributes, 7zip

I have a file in an archive that I wish to edit. I can open the archive with 7zip without any issues, and copy/modify/paste files into/from the archive (from within 7zip). The files have the following properties:

```
Modified: someDate
Attributes: -rwxrwxr-x
Host OS: Unix
```

There are more, but you get my point. I'm on a  windows system and as such can't make/edit the files without changing host OS and attributes (and the date ofcourse). Ideally what I'd like is a method to copy the properties of one file, and directly paste the over the properties of another file within the archive. So far I've tried a few freeware application on the internet (eg. I've tried [Attribute Change](https://www.petges.lu/download/) but it doesn't allow you to change much more than the date as far as I can tell).